# Symfony2 mongodb installation

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I've been following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) with a fresh install of symfony2 and everything goes fine until I hit the step where it says

```
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AcmeStoreBundle
```

which then gets me the error

```
Bundle AcmeStoreBundle does not contain any mapped documents. Did you maybe forget to define a mapping configuration?
```

I've followed the guide exactly other than in config.yml, where I had a custom URI connection string since I turned on auth. I don't believe this is the problem, but I'll post it anyways.

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017
        options: {}
default_database: admin
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Crazy question, but do you have any mapped documents?

Comment: How do I create a mapped document? I thought following that guide would create said document? I made a Document directory under the bundle and made a Product.php file. Update question since first code fragment is wrong.

Comment: And did you add annotiation or any other mapping to the document? Yml or XML or Annotiation? Where you describe the behavior for the "fields"?

Comment: Carreful, to have a right namespace however it could generate this error too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the following step:

Add Mapping Information (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#add-mapping-information)

When I do *not* do that step, I am getting the same error as you. It's either you didn't do it, or you did that step wrong, so I suggest you have a look at that again.

Comment: +1 for pretty close - I had the wrong namespace "Acme\DemoBundle\Product" instead of "Acme\DemoBundle\Document" !

Answer (score 3):

Aha, I've had this issue before. Keep Calm, you probably forgot to put `< ?php`

Answer (score 1):

So to be clear: DoctrineMongoDBBundle looks for a package called `Document` inside the bundle. If your entities are stored somewhere else, eg in an `Entity` package you will get this error.

The solution in that case is to point doctrine to the right folder like so:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                    type: annotation
                    dir: Entity
                    prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an entry to my configs.yml file. My document had all the annotations needed, but this was also needed.

```
## config.yml

# MongoDB Configuration
doctrine_mongodb:
    document_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            database: %database_name%
            retry_connect: %database_retry%
            retry_query: %database_retry%
            mappings:
                # Mapped bundles go here
                EccSpecialBundle: ~
                EccSuperBundle: ~
```

I realize this is not the solution to your problem, but I've run into this one a couple times now, so someone else might as well!